# How a visitor can keep choosing their next time <option> html

Tags: javascript, html

I am tired of searching for what I want
I want, after the visitor clicks on option 1, he will be transferred to an external website, and that his choice is kept for his upcoming visits so that he does not choose it again.

```
<html dir="ltr">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   var input = document.getElementById('mody');
   if (localStorage['mody']) { 
       input.value = localStorage['mody']; 
   }
   input.onchange = function () {
        localStorage['mody'] = this.value; 
    }
});
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>New Page 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<select name = 'mody' id = 'mody'>
<option value = 'modyselect'>Select</option>
<option value = 'mody1'>option 1</option>
<option value = 'mody2'>option 2</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use [`localStorage.setItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) and [`localStorage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

Comment: can you give me code for this plz

Comment: Just replace the two lines you are using in your code with the correct method I Link to.